# Problem connecting to SQL db from web app (Win7 x64 host)

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7

I am have a Silverlight app that connects to a local SQL Server db.  It works as expected on my WinXP computer, but not on the Win7 x64 computer.  (SQL Server 2008 installed.)
When I run the app, I get this error:

```
The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

My web.config, AppSettings:

```
<!-- For Development -->
<!--<add key="ConnectionInfo" value="data source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS; database=db003;integrated security=True;" />-->
<!-- For Win7 ?? -->
<add key="ConnectionInfo" value="server=(local); database=db003; Integrated Security=True;" />
```

Thanks for any suggestions, I suspect it is something simple that my limited SQL Server experience hasn't encountered yet...

Comment: seems to me the problem is lying at `server=(local);`

Comment: Found "server=(local)" here: http://odetocode.com/Articles/345.aspx

Comment: Do you see that port 1433 is open on your compouter?

Answer (score 0):

Try `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` instead of local.

**UPDATE**

I am positive that the express needs `\SQLEXPRESS`. On my machine I have:

- `MachineName\SQLEXPRESS`.
- SQL server browser is running
- Shared Memory, TCP/IP and Named Pipes are enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Changing server=(local) to server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS (with or w/o paren) still gave the same error.